# Creating a visual in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I wanted to create a power BI visual(a table) using data fields from two different tables. However , the data fields were not aligned on the table that was created.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbvEQ.png)

I was expecting the outcome to show data that was aligned properly on a table.

Comment: You need to provide more info then this. Some things to share or look into include, Model view with relationships, what are the columns of each table and how are they joined (relationship)